# Windows shares partly inaccessible after changing permissions. No backup

Tags: windows, permissions

OS: Windows 2008 R2
I tried to change permissions on a shared-folder "D:\Data" to permit access for Domain-Members,-Admins and -computers. I denied "EVERYONE" so, assuming improving the security.

After this process nobody had access. Undoing this by giving back full access to  "EVERONY" 
was aborted and failed. Copying the folder to an backup made the server hang up and reboot.

Now all files and folders till the pint of the aborted re-permissioning is accessible, all others can't be found.

What can I do to repair those inconsistent permissions?
Just setting back to EVERYONE fails...

Please help me, i am desperate and loosing my mind as being productive environment here.

Best regards,

emil :) 
* free charma  for every good human helping me - I promise to give back the help to others *

### Solution:

unclear - setting the right permissions a few times.
found out that old DomainAdministrator was in permission instead of new DomainAdministrator.  Maybe this was the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back into server manager while you're logged in as the admin account on that machine (the owner of the files in question). In the "File Services" area, you'll be able to change a few things.

First, you'll need to take control of everything again (as administrator). In NTSF permissions, make sure that administrator has full control of the highest level folder (Data, in this case, it will cascade down to the rest if you have it set up that way). After you change the NTSF permissions so administrator has full control, you can change the share permissions. Once you do that, everyone should have access again.